# Node.js/Puppeteer - DOM NodeList to JS Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I want to transform a NodeList into an object.

H1 is `object.name` and so on.

I still can't understand the exact behavior of `page.evaluate()`.

This is what I need:

[image]

And this is one of my attempts, but `gp` is always undefined:

```
await page.waitForNavigation();

const selG = 'body > div.content-home > div > div.box > div > div:nth- child(2) > div.col-md-12.no-padding > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-xs-12';
await page.waitForSelector(selG);
const g = await page.evaluate( (selG) => {
    let gp = document.querySelector(selG); //null
    let n = Array.from(gp.querySelectorAll('h1'), element => element.textContent);
    console.log(n[0]);
    return n;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.evaluate()` runs the function you're passing it directly into the browser and **it hasn't the scope** (access to variables) of the NodeJS script that launched Puppetter.

To fully understand, try this:

1 - copy your function as is

2 - wraps it into a self-invoking function `([your-function])()`, the result is the following (I added one more `console.log(selG);` line)

```
((selG) => {
  console.log(selG); // I added this line
  let gp = document.querySelector(selG);
  let n = Array.from(gp.querySelectorAll('h1'), element => element.textContent);
  console.log(n[0]);
  return n;
})()
```

3 - paste it directly into the devtools console

Doing so you're doing **more less** (from an understanding perspective) what `page.evaluate()` does, that is running the function you're passing it directly into the browser.
What's the result? It is `Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null` because, as you noted, `gp` is null.

But concentrate on the `console.log(selG);` I added... it logs `undefined`... that's the big issue!

Why does it happen?

Take a look at the function itself, the `selG` variable doesn't exist so the `let gp = document.querySelector(selG);` can't return anything. `selG` is defined into the script you used to launch Puppeteer but the function you pass to `page.evaluate()` will be run in the browser, not in the Node execution context.

Quoting directly the Puppeteer docs

> page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...args)
>
> pageFunction  Function to be evaluated in the page context
>
> ...args <...Serializable|JSHandle> Arguments to pass to pageFunction

use (as told by Grant) the second rest `args` to pass the `selG` variable to your function.

Following your original code with a little change

```
await page.waitForNavigation();

const selG = 'body > div.content-home > div > div.box > div > div:nth- child(2) > div.col-md-12.no-padding > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-xs-12';
await page.waitForSelector(selG);
const g = await page.evaluate( (SELECTOR) => {
    let gp = document.querySelector(SELECTOR);
    let n = Array.from(gp.querySelectorAll('h1'), element => element.textContent);
    console.log(n[0]);
    return n;
}, selG);
```

Please note:

- that I pass the `selG` variable (last line) to `pageFunction` (your function)
- the `pageFunction` receives a variable and stores it into the `SELECTOR` variable
- the `pageFunction` than consumes the `SELECTOR` received

**To summarize**: the function passed to `page.evaluate()` CAN'T consumes the variables declared outside it because it will be run into the browser, a context separated from your NodeJS script (wrote to launch Puppeteer itself).

Try my code, it should work without any change.
Let me know if it's enough clear.

**BONUS**

Remember that if you want to consume some DOM-related data you have at least three different methods that do the same.

Below you find an example of mine where I want to read the `href` attribute of the first link I find in a page. The first example uses `page.evaluate()` as you did, the latter two examples show you a different approach using some other Puppeteer APIs.

```
const SELECTOR = '[href]:not([href=""])';
let link;

// compare the three following examples, they all do the same
link = await page.evaluate((sel) => 
    document.querySelector(sel).getAttribute('href')
, SELECTOR);
link = await page.$eval(SELECTOR, el => el.getAttribute('href'));
link = await page.$(SELECTOR).getProperty('href').jsonValue();
```

Comment: could you help me? it became undefined again after I added my class. I need to create an object array https://jsfiddle.net/keypdamf/

Comment: @tramada provide me a GitHub repo and I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the the variable `selG` to [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) using the following method:

```
const g = await page.evaluate(selG => { /* ... */ }, selG);
```

> **Note:** Notice the that I added `selG` as a separate argument after the page function.
>
> ```
> page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...args)
> ```

This should prevent `document.querySelector(selG)` from returning `null`.